# Signing into ASP.NET identity with manually loaded credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I've created a very simple SSO solution. In the target application I can load the credentials successfully in the beginning of a request.

I would however use them to sign in and let ASP.NET Identity handle the credentials for all future requests (using the normal cookie middleware).

My first attempt was use `OnApplyRedirect` in the cookie middleware:

```
var provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
provider.OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
{
    if (ctx.Request.Query["s"] != null)
    {
        var ticket = LoadTicket(ctx.Request.Query["s"]);
        var uri = RemoveQueryStringByKey(ctx.Request.Uri.ToString(), "s");
        ticket.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
        ctx.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);
        ctx.Response.Redirect(uri);
        return;
    }
}
```

The credentials was not loaded for the next request :( (the cookie middleware redirected to the login page)

My second attempt was to create a complete authentication middleware and load the credentials and use `Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);` to signin.

```
public class SingleSignOnAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {

        var sessionIdentifier = Request.Query["s"];
        if (sessionIdentifier == null)
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);

        var ticket = LoadTicket(sessionIdentifier);
        if (ticket == null)
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);

        Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationTicket(ticket.Identity, ticket.Properties));
    }
}
```

The credentials was not loaded for the next request :( (the cookie middleware redirected to the login page)

I'm a bit lost. How can I load the claimsidentity manually and then have ASP.NET identity take over the credentials handling for all future requests?

**Update 1**

By making sure that the ClaimsIdentity have the same `AuthenticationType` as specified in the cookie middleware configuration I managed to get the authentication to work for normal MVC requests.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie", // <--- THIS STRING
    LoginPath = new PathString(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/Login")),
    Provider = provider
});
```

.. so it need to be the same here:

```
public class SingleSignOnAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {

        var sessionIdentifier = Request.Query["s"];
        if (sessionIdentifier == null)
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);

        var ticket = LoadTicket(sessionIdentifier);
        if (ticket == null)
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);

        ticket.Properties.IsPersistent = true;

        // ** LOOK HERE **
        //new identity, but with the correct authentication type
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ticket.Identity.Claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
        Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, identity);
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationTicket(identity, ticket.Properties));
    }
}
```

So that seems to work now. But my client side uses WebApi to be able to fetch information from the backend. And the application cookie seem to not be used for ASP.NET WebApi, even though it's in the same web project.

So how can I make WebApi load the same cookie?

Comment: hmm thats a hard requirement, normally i will not mix the two